# Trust CA and parent CA, but not other derivative CAs

Tags: tls, certificates, certificate-authority, openssl

I've got a problem with a client connecting to a server through an SSL-secured socket. The problem is with my requirements and the way the certificate chain gets validated.

I've got three CAs to sign client certificates:

- root CA: Self-signed.
- testers CA: Signed by root CA.
- production CA: Signed by root CA.

I want my server to trust all clients directly signed by root CA and directly signed by the testers CA, but deny any certificate signed by the production CA. I tried:

- root CA and testers CA in server's trust store: Production CA signed certificates pass because the root CA is trusted.
- testers CA only in server's trust store: Certs directly signed by root CA gets denied.

Is there any way to do this?

PD: Sorry about cross-posting this from stackoverflow (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29097058/trust-ca-and-parent-ca-but-not-other-derivative-cas). They told me this is probably a better place to get an answer.

Comment: Thanks, didn't found that. So the only way is to implement my own chain validation (not standard x509 chain validation) or change to a CA hierarchy that fits better.

Comment: Yes, I'd advise you to set up a separate root for your testing certs.